# verification while entering the details in mobile number field

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I like to have an edittext field for entering mobile number with  minimum 10 characters long, I know to do that by using a setonClicklistener in the submit button, but I like to know whether that checking is possible while entering the details itself that is, before clicking the button, if someone enters only 9 numbers at that time itself it need to give an alert that mobile number to have 10 numbers. I have seen that in some apps but don't know how to do that in android studio.  If any one knows please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, you can do it by attaching a text watcher.

**Follow the steps below:**

```
phone.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
  // the changes will be provided there 
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
 // here you need to write s.toString() and you will 
   //get the updated text automatically and then you can check it's  
   //length and show the warning accordingly
}
});
```

NOTE:: replace phone with your own edit text Name

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.**

Comment: ..Thanks for the answer .. can you able to tell me the difference between afterTextChanged and onTextChanged, I felt both methods works almost the same way